# Google AdWords add Conversion Value afterwards

Tags: google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

i have a site selling a single product. :)

The product is highly customizable so the value of a conversion is unclear at the moment my page triggers the conversion. Usually i need ~ 3 (!) days until i have a signed contract with the final price and my value which i'd need in AdWords to run my cost-oriented calculation.

Is it somehow possible to save a session with a conversion ID or sth. like that and submit the value when available? Technically it'd be possible for me to create this, but does google provide an api to submit this data with such a delay?

thanks for any information.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question:

You can use the *GCLID* ID Google provides with each AdWords click. Then submit the conversions manually via Excel/CSV upload or use API as shown in the article.

[**Tracking offline conversions**](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2998031?hl=en)